# SQL Optimization w/o Creating Index

Tags: python, sql, oracle, performance, pandas

I'm trying to optimize a SQL query that runs on an Oracle Database. The query is:

```
SELECT Col_5, Col_10, Col_15, Col_20, ..., Col_100
FROM TABLE
WHERE Col_5 = 37 AND Col_10 IS NOT NULL
```

TABLE has 100 million plus rows and is updated frequently. It looks like:

```
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+------------+-----+---------+
| Col_1  | Col_2 | ... | Col_5 | ... |  Col_10    | ... | Col_100 |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+------------+-----+---------+
| 12     | Bob   | ... | 18    | ... | 08/06/1992 | ... | 12.6    |
| 6      | Mike  | ... | 37    | ... | NULL       | ... | 18.0    |
| 18     | Sally | ... | 6     | ... | NULL       | ... | 16.3    |
| :      | :     | :   | :     | :   | :          | :   | :       |
| 94     | Eli   | ... | 37    | ... | 01/22/2003 | ... | 19      |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+------------+-----+---------+
```

My query returns about 10 million rows but takes about 30 minutes to run. I should add that this query is read into a Pandas DataFrame in Python via pd.read_sql(SQL_query, data_connection). Once it's in Python, all subsequent data manipulations are performed within seconds. For this reason, I have ruled out the possibility of simply adding more WHERE clauses to reduce the number of rows returned as I would like to perform operations on all of the returned 10 million or so rows.

Unfortunately, creating an index is not an option. Given this limitation, is there anyway for me to speed up my query?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider Partition/Sub-Partition ?

Comment: Why is an index no option?

Comment: @shrek - Partitioning is a **chargeable extra option** on the Enterprise License, and by no means a guaranteed performance enhancement when we look at the wider picture (i.e. what else uses the table). So this is not a safe suggestion.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - the query returns about 10% of the table. It is unlikely 10 million indexed reads will outperform a full table scan.

Comment: @APC, if you could partition the table on,`Col_5` then you would gain some performance because you avoid full table scan.

Comment: The shown result does not mach the condition 'where Col_5 =37'

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - probably at the expense of all the other queries on that table which don't select on `col_5`. That's what I meant by *'the wider picture'*. We know nothing about the OP's situation, not least whether they are licensed to use Partitioning option.

Comment: @shrek Good idea but I don't have the proper permission to create a partition. Any other ideas?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Good idea but I don't have the proper permission to create an index. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns about 10% of the table's rows. It selects multiple columns from across the whole row.  Assuming the posted sample data is representative there is no clumping of data and selected rows will come from all through the table.

So indexing won't help you. You need a Full Table Scan.

Run an Explain Plan on your query to make sure you are using one. If for some reason you are running some form of indexed read fix that (for instance by refreshing stale statistics). Beyond that there aren't many ways to tune a Full Table Scan: if you have an Enterprise Edition and multiple CPUs available then parallel query may help.

But, let's row back a minute.

> "My query returns about 10 million rows but takes about 30 minutes to run."

Where is the bottleneck?  Almost certainly not the database. 10 million rows of ~20 columns is a hefty amount of data but a Full Table Scan on one table should run in a couple of minutes, if not much less (depending on the beefiness of your server).

It is quite likely to be the network (unless you are running this query locally, that is pandas client is on the database server). You are passing many, many packets across the network. You may be running into a limit on available bandwidth, so talk to your network admin team (or install [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)!). If network latency is the issue check whether setting `pd.read_sql() chunksize` helps.

The other thing to consider is client memory: dataframes are in-memory structures, so you may be loading more data than the client can handle. Anything you can do to reduce the total amount of selected data will help.  Revisit the projection of the query and remove any columns you don't need for the subsequent processing.

---

> ' EXPLAIN PLAN FOR command isn't returning anything'

EXPLAIN PLAN populates a table. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601). You need to query the table to get the plan out. The DBMS_XPLAN built-in package is your best friend here. [Check it out](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xplan.htm). Some IDEs (like PL/SQL Developer) handle this transaparently.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I have two follow-up questions. (1) When I use an *EXPLAIN* command on a query to Teradata, it works. For this particular problem, I'm querying an Oracle database and the *EXPLAIN PLAN FOR* command isn't returning anything. Any ideas? (2) This query pretty much maxes out my computer's memory. After running `pd.read_sql(sql,con)`, I cast all columns `.astype('categorical')` to reduce memory usage. Is there anyway to do this immediately upon import, something analogous to `pd.read_excel(url, dtype='category')`? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm an Oracle person. My experience of pandas is limited to playing around with some Jupyter notebooks.